# Run sql script automatically when building Spring boot project

Tags: sql, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot rest Api with a MySql database. It currently only has one table, so in order to create the table if it doesn't exist, I just have some Java code that does the job when the server is initialized.

But I don't think that's the right way to go. I believe a better way would be to have an external sql file which would be run from Spring each time I run my project.

So, let's say I have a file called TABLES.sql with all the db tables. How can I configure Spring to run this automatically each time it boots?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Just for further clarification, I have configured my project to run on a Docker db on a "dev" environment, and on a real instance on a "prod" environment. And the db user, pass etc are all configurable. I'm just messing around basically to learn stuff. :)

Comment: Do you use maven?

Comment: Yes, I have maven 3 for my project

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [schema migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool. We use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) in our project and it works great.

With this you write incremental SQL scripts which all run to give you the final version of database. To actually run the migrations you need to use flyway's migrate goal.

```
mvn -P<profile> flyway:migrate
```

Comment: Or you use the Spring Boot integration of Flyway and let the application validate and migrate the DB schema. Because just if you build the application, doesn't mean this version immediately run on the environment which you just migrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hibernate, a file named `import.sql` in the root of the classpath will be executed on startup. This can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful, but probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production. It is a Hibernate feature (nothing to do with Spring).

Get more info here: [Database initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've found what I were looking for. I can have a schema-mysql.sql file with all my table creates etc, according to this spring guide:

[Initialize a database using Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)

This is basically what I want

Thanks for your help though!